# Why does apt-get update get a 403 from private-ppas for purchases in the software-center?

Tags: apt, ubuntu-one, software-center, ppa

Here's the `apt-get update` output on the lines with a 403 error:

```
W: Failed to fetch https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/bit-trip-beat/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  The requested URL returned error: 403    
W: Failed to fetch https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/bit-trip-beat/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  The requested URL returned error: 403
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Here's what's in `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list | grep ppa`:

```
deb https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/bit-trip-beat/ubuntu precise main #Added by software-center; credentials stored in /etc/apt/auth.conf
```

Here's a redacted version of my auth.conf:

```
machine private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/bit-trip-beat/ubuntu
login dlamblin
password 3..................6
```

That's a hash presumably for the purchase processed through my Ubuntu One account for the Humble Bundle for Android 3 (and Windows/Mac/Linux).

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your Launchpad login credentials to `apt.conf` (probably the hash) or use the method of:

```
https://user:pass@private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/bit-trip-beat/ubuntu
```

To log in.

Comment: Could you elaborate Braiam? I'm affected by this bug in the same way and my _auth.conf_ has different user names for different commercial PPAs because I changed my Launchpad ID.

Changing the username in the file doesn't help - it just gets reverted when I try to reinstall via USC or apt-get.

So are you saying to format the url in that file differently or to log in to USC with the old credentials (which I imagine isn't possible).

Comment: @TenLeftFingers if it works for some, but others not, just copy (after doing backups of the original file) the ones that works over the ones that doesn't.

Comment: as I say 'Changing the username in the file doesn't help - it just gets reverted when I try to reinstall via USC or apt-get.' so on 14.04 at least it seems it rewrites the line before applying it.